# undefined method to each do Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, each

I have two tables: Dimensions and Task. For each dimension have N task.
so in Task Controller i have this:

```
def new
  @dimensions =  Dimension.all
  @dimensions.each do |dimension|
    @task = Task.new
  end
end
```

and the view Task this

```
<h1>Tasks#new</h1>
<%= form_for(@task) do |task| %>
  <div class='service'>
    <li class="col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4><%= task.name %></h4>
          <p><%= task.description %></p>
        </div>
        <span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but on the task view it shows me this error message

> undefined method 'name'
>
> undefined method 'descripcion'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
def new
  @dimensions =  Dimension.all
  @dimensions.each do |dimension|
    @task = dimension.tasks.new //OR @task = dimension.build_tasks
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks :), I think can also use the gem cocoon i'm gonna try